# Count number of rows after filter in Google Visualisation Table

Tags: google-visualization, dashboard, google-datatable

I have implement various controls in a Google Visualisation Table for multiple filter: CategoryFilter, StringFilter and NumberRangeFilter like this exemple
http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/Ena84/

Is it possible know the number of rows visualised in table after every filter settings?
Thank you.

```
function drawTable() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
data.addColumn('string', 'Team');
data.addColumn('string', 'Nationality');
data.addColumn('number', 'Height');
data.addColumn('number', 'Weight');
data.addColumn('number', 'OverallRating');
data.addColumn('string', 'Foot');
data.addRows([
    ['MESSI','FC BARCELONA','ARGENTINA',169,67,25,'Left foot'],
    ['A. INIESTA','FC BARCELONA','SPAIN',170,65,28,'Right foot'],
    ['XAVI','FC BARCELONA','SPAIN',170,68,32,'Right foot']
]);

var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));

var stringFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'StringFilter',
    containerId: 'string_filter_div',
    options: {
        filterColumnIndex: 0
    }
});

var numberRangeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'NumberRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'numnber_range_filter_div',
    options: {
        filterColumnIndex: 5,
        minValue: 0,
        maxValue: 100,
        ui: {
            label: 'Overall Rating'
        }
    }
});

var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'table_div',
    options: {
        showRowNumber: true
    }
});

dashboard.bind([stringFilter, numberRangeFilter], [table]);
dashboard.draw(data);
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['controls'], callback: drawTable});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

once the `'ready'` event fires on any of the controls, charts, or dashboard

you can use the `getDataTable` method on any of the controls or charts

to `getNumberOfRows`

see following working snippet...

```js
function drawTable() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Team');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Nationality');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Height');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Weight');
  data.addColumn('number', 'OverallRating');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Foot');
  data.addRows([
      ['MESSI','FC BARCELONA','ARGENTINA',169,67,25,'Left foot'],
      ['A. INIESTA','FC BARCELONA','SPAIN',170,65,28,'Right foot'],
      ['XAVI','FC BARCELONA','SPAIN',170,68,32,'Right foot']
  ]);

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));

  var stringFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      controlType: 'StringFilter',
      containerId: 'string_filter_div',
      options: {
          filterColumnIndex: 0
      }
  });

  var numberRangeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      controlType: 'NumberRangeFilter',
      containerId: 'numnber_range_filter_div',
      options: {
          filterColumnIndex: 5,
          minValue: 0,
          maxValue: 100,
          ui: {
              label: 'Overall Rating'
          }
      }
  });

  var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'Table',
      containerId: 'table_div',
      options: {
          showRowNumber: true
      }
  });

  dashboard.bind([stringFilter, numberRangeFilter], [table]);
  
  google.visualization.events.addListener(dashboard, 'ready', function () {
    // get number of rows
    console.log(table.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows());
  });
  
  dashboard.draw(data);
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['controls'], callback: drawTable});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="string_filter_div"></div>
<div id="numnber_range_filter_div"></div>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```